# How to host an ADF application in Tomcat Server?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I need to host an ADF application in a Tomcat Server. Is it possible ?
How can it be done ?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/dana/entry/how_to_deploy_a_11g_adf_applic_1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to deploy Oracle-ADF application to Tomcat 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628887/trying-to-deploy-oracle-adf-application-to-tomcat-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What is more Oracle ADF license is bound to Oracle Application Server license. I think it is not legally possible to have license on ADF framework and run it on any other stack than Weblogic."

This is not quite correct. WebLogic Server and Websphere are the two servers ADF is certified on. This doesn't mean it is not supported on other servers. ADF has a single licence which allows you to run it on other servers. With upcoming JDeveloper versions we increase the number of certified servers.

Comment: Frank, does it mean that I can just buy a license for ADF and deploy it on whatever server I want without buying Weblogic server?

Comment: Frank, any chance Tomcat is certified in the upcoming versions?

Comment: Yes you can buy a stand alone ADF runtime license. Depending on which parts of ADF you are using your success in deploying on Tomcat with change.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the ADF framework runs on a Java EE 5 stack. Building your own Java EE stack on Tomcat is a quite hard task. I'd rather run it on WebLogic server as it is intended. What is more Oracle ADF license is bound to Oracle Application Server license. I think it is not legally possible to have license on ADF framework and run it on any other stack than Weblogic.